# Combining multithreading and multiprocessing with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a function which is both highly I/O dependent and CPU-intensive. I tried to parallelize it by multiprocessing and multithreading but it is stuck. This question [was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994478/a-threadpoolexecutor-inside-a-processpoolexecutor) before but in a different setting. My function is fully independent and returns nothing. Why is it stuck? How can it be fixed?

```
import concurrent.futures
import os
import numpy as np
import time


ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    x**2

def multithread_accounts(AccountNumbers, f, n_threads = 2):

    slices = np.array_split(AccountNumbers, n_threads)
    slices = [list(i) for i in slices]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(f, slices)



def parallelize_distribute(AccountNumbers, f, n_threads = 2, n_processors = os.cpu_count()):

    slices = np.array_split(AccountNumbers, n_processors)
    slices = [list(i) for i in slices]

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_processors) as executor:
        executor.map( lambda x: multithread_accounts(x, f, n_threads = n_threads) , slices)
        
parallelize_distribute(ids, f, n_processors=2, n_threads=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't make time to explain all this, so I'll just give code "that works". I urge you to start with something simpler, because the learning curve is non-trivial. Leave numpy out of it at first; stick to *only* threads at first; then move to *only* processes; and unless you're an expert don't try to parallelize anything other than named module-level functions (no, not function-local anonymous lambdas).

As often happens, the error messages you "should be" getting are being suppressed because they occur asynchronously so there's no good way to report them. Liberally add `print()` statements to see how far you're getting.

Note: I stripped numpy out of this, and added the stuff needed so it runs on Windows too.  I expect using numpy's `array_split()` instead would work fine, but I didn't have numpy handy on the machine I was on at the time.

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import os
import time

def array_split(xs, n):
    from itertools import islice
    it = iter(xs)
    result = []
    q, r = divmod(len(xs), n)
    for i in range(r):
        result.append(list(islice(it, q+1)))
    for i in range(n - r):
        result.append(list(islice(it, q)))
    return result
    
ids = range(1, 11)

def f(x):
    print(f"called with {x}")
    time.sleep(5)
    x**2

def multithread_accounts(AccountNumbers, f, n_threads=2):
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_threads) as executor:
        for slice in array_split(AccountNumbers, n_threads):
            executor.map(f, slice)

def parallelize_distribute(AccountNumbers, f, n_threads=2, n_processors=os.cpu_count()):
    slices = array_split(AccountNumbers, n_processors)
    print("top slices", slices)
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_processors) as executor:
        executor.map(multithread_accounts, slices,
                                           [f] * len(slices),
                                           [n_threads] * len(slices))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parallelize_distribute(ids, f, n_processors=2, n_threads=2)
```

BTW, I suggest this makes more sense for the threaded part:

```
def multithread_accounts(AccountNumbers, f, n_threads=2):
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_threads) as executor:
        executor.map(f, AccountNumbers)
```

That is, there's really no need to split the list yourself here - the threading machinery will split it up itself. It's possible you missed that in your original attempts, because the `ThreadPoolExecutor()` call in the code you posted forgot to specify the `max_workers` argument.